# Возвращение функции из функции

Tags: javascript, функции, функциональное-программирование

Для чего используется строка return undefined;? Я удалила, но вроде результат компиляции не изменился. И когда actiion равен undefined?

```js
function menu(n){
  
    if(n==1) return function(x, y){ 
      return x+y;
      }
    else if(n==2) return function(x, y){
       return x - y;
       }
    else if(n==3) return function(x, y){ 
      return x * y;
      }
    return undefined;
}
 
for(var i=1; i < 5; i++){
    var action = menu(i);
    if(action!==undefined){
        var result = action(5, 4);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция по умолчанию возвращает `undefined`, поэтому после удаления последней строки в функции поведение не меняется. Это строка просто дублирует неявное поведение. Можно написать по разному

```
function a() {}; // вернет undefined
function b() {return}; // тоже вернет undefined
function c() {return undefined}; //опять тоже самое
```

Касательно второго вопроса: когда ни одно из условий не сработает, в вашем случае это если передали не 1, 2 или 3

Comment: Ага, понятно. А вот я в цикле for(var i=4; i < 7; i++){...} для i задала значение 4 чтоб function menu(n){ } не сработал. Но код после компиляции в консоль не возвращает слово undefined, хотя должен же был возвращать. И как вы написали action передала параметры 0, 4, 5 по отдельности, и при этом тоже код не возвращает слово undefined. А так все ясно.

Comment: @Afina у вас вывод в консоль под условием, в которое при неверных данных код не заходит. вынесите его из условия тогда увидите `undefined`

Comment: Когда вынесла console.log(result); за условия, увидела undefined при i=4. Но если значение i оставить меньше 4, то есть так for(var i=1; i < 5; i++), а console.log(result); вывести за условия тогда она выводит в консоль 9 1 20 20. Здесь 2-ой 20 почему выводится? Почему-то тогда тоже некорректно работает. P.S. На первом ответе я это предложение перепутала -> И как вы написали action передала параметры 0, 4, 5 по отдельности, и при этом тоже код не возвращает слово undefined.

Comment: @Afina ответы у вас правильные, 9 - это сумма, 1 - разница, 20 - произведение, дальше результат не меняется, потому что вы снова не попадаете в условие, поэтому сохраняется старое значение ( 20 )

Comment: Все понятно. Если написать i<=6 выводится вообще 3 раза 20. А если вывести console.log(result); за функции, тогда вообще выводится только 20. Эта все уже тема касающаяся циклов.

Comment: @Afina эта тема касается области видимости) Если что-то непонятно, то задавайте вопросы или так пишите)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99885/discussion-between-afina-and-thisman).

Comment: @Afina ну давайте

Comment: Увидев -> Пожалуйста, избегайте развёрнутых обсуждений в комментариях. я хотела перейти по ссылке в чат, но результат -> Не удается получить доступ к сайту ( Кстати да я ошиблась, эта тема области видимости, идет после функции

Comment: @Afina щас чат доступен

Comment: Я попыталась.., Не удается получить доступ к сайту Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Afina  у меня в профиле есть ссылка, можете туда написать, либо просто дальше задавайте вопросы, как вам удобнее

Answer (score 1):

Эта строка здесь не нужна. Если функция завершается без исполнения команды `return`, то результат этой функции - `undefined`. Смысл `return undefined;` - показать, что программист не забыл что-то вернуть, а возвращает `undefined` специально.